# Highlight duplicates across a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight duplicates across a workbook of 12 sheets.

We track ID#s and I want to highlight the cell if an ID# (value) is on any of the other sheets.

When I use the below code in the "This Workbook" it applies within a sheet, and not across the multiple sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

'Duplicates will be highlighted in red
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
For Each col In Target.Columns
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, col.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, col.Column).End(xlUp))
    Debug.Print Rng.Address

    For Each cel In col
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
            Set c = Rng.Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Set c = Rng.FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next col
```

Comment: You should be able to loop through each sheet using `For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and apply the code to each sheet.

Comment: are all id's in the same column across all worksheets?

Comment: Yes, the ID#s are all in column "A" of each worksheet.

Comment: Posted an answer. Check it out

Comment: You may want to refresh the page as I was trying the code and have made some edits.

Comment: Siddharth Rout any suggestions to the issue in your VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example that should give you some ideas and point you in the right direction.
If you have an questions, let me know.

```
Sub collected_ids_example()
    ' enable microsoft scripting runtime --> tools - references
    ' For convenience I put all code in 2 subs/functions
    ' This code assumes you want every cell with a duplicate id highlighted.
    ' Although it is easy enough to modify that if you want.

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim id_to_addresses As New Dictionary
    Dim id_ As Range

    ' For every worksheet collect all ids and their associated adressses
    ' for the specified range.
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each id_ In sh.Range("A4:A100")
            If Not IsEmpty(id_) Then
                If Not id_to_addresses.Exists(id_.Value) Then
                    Set id_to_addresses(id_.Value) = New Collection
                End If
                id_to_addresses(id_.Value).Add get_full_address(id_)
            End If
        Next id_
    Next sh

    ' Color each cell with a duplicate id
    Dim collected_id As Variant
    Dim adresses As Collection
    Dim c As Range
    For Each collected_id In id_to_addresses
        Dim duplicate_address As Variant
        Set adresses = id_to_addresses(collected_id)

        'You have a duplicate if an id is associated with more than 1 addrress
        If adresses.Count >= 2 Then
            For Each duplicate_address In adresses
                Set c = Range(duplicate_address)
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Next duplicate_address
        End If
    Next collected_id
End Sub

Private Function get_full_address(c As Range) As String
    get_full_address = "'" & c.Parent.Name & "'!" & c.Address(External:=False)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Frank. I am very new to VBA, could you please adjust this code to highlight cell range A4:A100 on each sheet?

Comment: I changed to code as you requested. If you any more questions, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

What this code does is loops through the values of Col A in the sheet which gets activated and then it searches the Col A of all the remaining worksheets and if it finds the ID then it colors the cell background to red.

**TRIED AND TESTED**

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have a problem understanding it. If you still do then simply post back :)

Try this

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim lRow As Long, wsLRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String

    With Sh
        '~~> Get last row in Col A of the sheet
        '~~> which got activated
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Remove existing Color from the column
        '~~> This is to cater for any deletions in the
        '~~> other sheets so that cells can be re-colored
        .Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        '~~> Loop through the cells of the sheet which
        '~~> got activated
        For i = 1 To lRow
            '~~> Store the ID in a variable
            strSearch = .Range("A" & i).Value

            '~~> loop through the worksheets in the workbook
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                '~~> This is to ensure that it doesn't
                '~~> search itself
                If ws.Name <> Sh.Name Then
                    '~~> Get last row in Col A of the sheet
                    wsLRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    '~~> Use .Find to quick check for the duplicate
                    Set aCell = ws.Range("A1:A" & wsLRow).Find(What:=strSearch, _
                                                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                               MatchCase:=False, _
                                                               SearchFormat:=False)

                    '~~> If found then color the cell red and exit the loop
                    '~~> No point searching rest of the sheets
                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        Sh.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next ws
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth, Thank you for the help. This works almost as intended, there is a couple things I would like to change: #1: i changed now to be a sheet_selectionchange (not sure why I didn't use that from the start) and #2: I also need it to check for duplicates on the same sheet (doesn't seem to work with the code as is)..

Comment: Also, it seems that if you have a similar combination of numbers (i.e. 123456 & 654321) it highlights them both as duplicates...