# Excel VBA mark duplicate on colA (work on all worksheet include activesheet)

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, find

I'd like to mark duplicate on all Worksheet in Workbook. Below the code mark only duplicate if the duplicate exist on other worksheet. 
I'd like to mark them also if them exist on Activesheet. 
(much better if it possible to mark on different color if duplicate exist only in Activesheet)

Here's a link for solution on similar case, What I need to solve. [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25252503/5493335) "loops through the values of Col A in the sheet which gets activated and then it searches the Col A of all the remaining worksheets and if it finds the ID then it colors the cell background to red. by Siddhart Rout"

I add only one change to this code to eliminate color on empty rows. 
But those code is mark(on red color) only if duplicate is one another Worksheet.
I wonder to makr on diffrent color if I found duplicate on activeworksheet.

I will trying to do myself and change the condition with else but It doesn't work. Could anybody get me some help to solve that issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
        Dim lRow As Long, wsLRow As Long, i As Long
        Dim aCell As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim strSearch As String

        With Sh
            '~~> Get last row in Col A of the sheet
            '~~> which got activated
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> Remove existing Color from the column
            '~~> This is to cater for any deletions in the
            '~~> other sheets so that cells can be re-colored
            .Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

            '~~> Loop through the cells of the sheet which
            '~~> got activated
            For i = 1 To lRow
                '~~> Store the ID in a variable
                strSearch = .Range("A" & i).Value
                if strSearch <> "" then 'eliminated color empty cell

                '~~> loop through the worksheets in the workbook
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    '~~> This is to ensure that it doesn't
                    '~~> search itself
                    If ws.Name <> Sh.Name Then
                        '~~> Get last row in Col A of the sheet
                        wsLRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                        '~~> Use .Find to quick check for the duplicate
                        Set aCell = ws.Range("A1:A" & wsLRow).Find(What:=strSearch, _
                                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                                   MatchCase:=False, _
                                                                   SearchFormat:=False)

                        '~~> If found then color the cell red and exit the loop
                        '~~> No point searching rest of the sheets
                        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                            Sh.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next ws
                   End if 
            Next i
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `If ws.Name <> Sh.Name` Then line and end if underneath in line with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the following refactoring of your code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim IDsRng As Range, IDCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim foundInOtherSheet As Boolean, foundInActiveSheet As Boolean

    With Sh
        Set IDsRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| set the IDs range as all column A not empty cells with some "text" content
        '~~> Remove existing Color from the column
        '~~> This is to cater for any deletions in the other sheets so that cells can be re-colored
        .Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With


    For Each IDCell In IDsRng '<--| Loop through ID cells (i.e. column A "text" cells of the activated sheet)
        '~~> Store the ID in a variable
        strSearch = IDCell.Value

        foundInActiveSheet = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(IDsRng, strSearch) > 1 '<--| count possible dupes in active sheet
        foundInOtherSheet = False '<--| initialize it at every new ID

        '~~> loop through the worksheets in the workbook
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            '~~> This is to ensure that it doesn't search itself
            If ws.Name <> Sh.Name Then
                With ws
                    foundInOtherSheet = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)), strSearch) > 1
                    If foundInOtherSheet Then Exit For '~~> If found then color then no point searching rest of the sheets
                End With
            End If
        Next

        Select Case True '<--| now act accordingly to where duplicates have been found
            Case foundInOtherSheet And Not foundInActiveSheet '<--| if duplicates found in "other" sheets only
                IDCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '<--| red
            Case foundInOtherSheet And foundInActiveSheet '<--| if duplicates found in "other" sheets and in "active" one too
                IDCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '<--| yellow
            Case Not foundInOtherSheet And foundInActiveSheet '<--| if duplicates found in "active" sheets only
                IDCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 14 '<--| green
        End Select

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thank You for replly User3598756. it is working on Your computer because I have errors?    One as important information I need to compare numbers not a text. But for test i try to do with text and I still have a eroor 1004 debug with this line  [code]In line foundInActiveSheet = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(IDsRng, strSearch) > 1[/code]

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solves your question please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!

Comment: user3598756 - I wrote that Your code  doesn't work. * I need to check for numbers duplicates. ** I put the code into the workbook.

Comment: edited to take all those `Specialcells()` off so that IDs can be whatever value you need

Answer (score 0):

remove the `If ws.Name <> Sh.Name` Then line and `end if` underneath in line with it.

Comment: It's not working Nathan.  I wrote that before  I was trying to change many of conditions. After remove those line the code is mark on red everyValue not only duplicate... Nathan is not as easy as looking.  Thanks for Your attention on those issue.