# Why can I not use Private Sub Workbook_Open(ByVal Sh As Object) any workaround?

Tags: excel, vba

I want the code to run when workbook loads. I am using `Private Sub Workbook_Open(ByVal Sh As Object)`, but it throws an error "Procedure error does not match description of event" - Any ideas please, as `Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)` works.

But I want code to run when workbook opens.

I know that `Private Sub Workbook_Open(ByVal Sh As Object)` is not allowed.

Comment: You can't just make up your own events in this way - the options appear in the dropdown at the top of the VBE. It doesn't make sense for a workbook open event to have a sheet parameter. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's that parameter you are putting in the `Workbook_Open` routine. If your workbook opens, then what you would anticipate the "Sheet" would be that would be passed to that parameter?  Remove the parameter so it's just `Sub Workbook_Open()` and rerun. If you need the sheet that is front and center, then in that sub you can query for `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: I am trying to use the code on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251833/excel-vba-to-highlight-duplicates-across-a-workbook/55599717#55599717 It works fine using 'sheetactivate' but I need code to work on workbook 'open'

Comment: @user10127073 ... it works in that answer because that event handler exists.  As was previously said, you can't just make up event handlers that tinker with standard ones.  Also, if you think about it, why would the workbook open event care about passing a sheet?  It doesn't make sense.  I've tried to answer your question to see if it helps you get your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment, as previously stated by a few, you can't just change a signature of a standard Excel event handler.

However, you can work within that handler and get access to the worksheets within the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet

    For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Do something with the sheet that you're interested in.
    Next
End Sub
```

I hope that helps.